# insert single quote before inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

My php code returns some value, I am trying to insert in database.

```
$string =  '1,here,Skincare composition against free radicals'; //this is returned

'(insert into import (S.No,Name,Title)) values ($string)'
```

Need to convert that string in proper format to insert in db

```
'1','here','Skincare composition against free radicals'  //This is expected
```

implode should do it? But I dont know how?

Comment: That should work, since your SQL is a string...

Comment: @christopher But you need `'`s, right?

Comment: @irrelephant Ah duh. Kuya's answer is good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try,

```
$string =  "1,here,Skincare composition against free radicals";
$varList = explode(",", $string);
$newQuery = "INSERT INTO `import` (`S.No`,`Name`,`Title`) VALUES ('" . $varList[0] . "','" . $varList[1] . "','" . $varList[2] . "')";
```

but the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to how learn to protect from it,

- [**How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Other Source

- [PHP **Explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: or even better, use prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yep, that's why I added link on how to protect using prepared statement `:D`